# How to check all values inside array are there in another array?

Tags: javascript

How to compare the array of an object with the array.

```
Array Comparing : ['Men','Women']
```

**Array Object**

```
var obj = [{
{'id':1,'value':['Men','Women','Animal']},
{'id':2,'value':['Men','Women']},
{'id':3,'value':['Women','Animal']},
{'id':4,'value':['Animal']},
{'id':5,'value':['Men']}
}]
```

**After Comparision result should be**

```
obj = [{
{'id':2,'value':['Men','Women']},
{'id':5,'value':['Men']}
}]
```

Is there any direct method? I don't want to use 2 loops and index operation.

Comment: What mean "is having a value of another array." ?

Comment: Could be done with filter method and your custom logic, I guess

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai My bad i meant comparing array of object with array

Comment: You can use ES6 Array Filter To Get The Difference. with this method u can decide which items to exclude from the original array or include similar items as a new array

Comment: used FIlter + every to get result thanks